# converting vs2008 to vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a mvc application on VS2008.

How can i create a new solution file which need to support VS2010.

Comment: Simply opening vs2008 solution in vs2010 doesn't work?

Comment: Worked for me. Just opened 08 project in 10 Studio. Converted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio will do that for you. If you need to keep the old solution file, you have two options: VS will let you keep a backup of the old files, or you can upgrade a copy of the original solution.